# How to access variable declared inside the IF Condition surrounded with sudo su EOF block

Tags: shell

I have a Shell Script file name TestLog.sh 
Inside I have a variable assigned with some value inside IF condition. I want to access that variable outside IF condition in the same file.

```
#!/bin/sh

sudo su <<EOF
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
LOG_LOCATION="Base/reports/jtl_logs"
CSV_LOCATION="Base/reports/csv"
LOOP_COUNT=30
elif [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
LOG_LOCATION="Base/reports/$1/jtl_logs"
CSV_LOCATION="Base/reports/$1/csv"
LOOP_COUNT=30
elif [ $# -eq 2 ]; then
LOG_LOCATION="Base/reports/$1/jtl_logs"
CSV_LOCATION="Base/reports/$1/csv"
LOOP_COUNT=$2
fi

echo $LOG_LOCATION
echo $CSV_LOCATION
echo $LOOP_COUNT
EOF
```

I call my script as

```
TestLog.sh 19.10.11 3
```

Expected Output:

```
Base/reports/19.10.11/jtl_logs
Base/reports/19.10.11/csv
3
```

Actual Output:

```
Display nothing
```

Comment: I don't see any `if` in your code; I see only `elif` and `fi`. Please post the complete code.

Comment: Done. Seems like formatting issue. Lets me know if anything is needed.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://tio.run/##S0kszvj/X1lRPykzT784g4srM00hWkFFWUE3tVDBQCHWWqEkIzWPy8ffPd7H39kxxNPfz1bJKbE4Vb8otSC/qKRYP6skJz4nP71Yics5OAyXouTiMiWgIf4B8c7@oX4htsYGXKk5yFYZEmOViiFxtgHVEbTQiMYWqhhxpWVycaUmZ@QrqCBbARVCNg2uCqb7////hpZ6hgZ6hob/jQE).

Comment: Provides **Expected Output:** here. What OS? Please show the output of `sh --version`. Also show output of `ls -al TestLog.sh`.

Comment: Sorry @melpomene. IF condition is surrounded inside sudo su EOF block. Have updated the code snippet

Comment: Variables you set in one shell are not visible in another shell process.

Comment: But IF condition and echo statements are in same shell right?

Comment: Because you use `<<EOF` instead of `<<'EOF'`, the variables are evaluated by the *outer* shell, before the inner one is started.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo su <<EOF
```

The expansion of the variables inside here document with unquoted "limit string" (the `<<EOF` part)  happens *before* the `sudo` command is executed.

```
a=1
sudo <<EOF
a=2
echo $a
EOF
```

The `$a` above is expanded first, so first it looks like:

```
sudo <<'EOF'
a=2
echo 1
EOF
```

then `sudo` command is run with the input.

You can force the shell not to expand the variables inside the here document by quoting the limit string. As I showed above with `<<'EOF'`. If the limit string is quoted, no expansion happens inside, the text is taken as it is. But that would make you jump into another problem - the `$#` will be 0 inside `sudo`, cause you didn't pass any parameters.

Also `sudo su` makes no sense. Just `sudo` or just `su`.

One solution could be such a construct:

```
sudo sh -c '
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
  LOG_LOCATION="Base/reports/jtl_logs"
  CSV_LOCATION="Base/reports/csv"
  LOOP_COUNT=30
elif [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
  LOG_LOCATION="Base/reports/$1/jtl_logs"
  CSV_LOCATION="Base/reports/$1/csv"
  LOOP_COUNT=30
elif [ $# -eq 2 ]; then
  LOG_LOCATION="Base/reports/$1/jtl_logs"
  CSV_LOCATION="Base/reports/$1/csv"
  LOOP_COUNT=$2
fi

echo $LOG_LOCATION
echo $CSV_LOCATION
echo $LOOP_COUNT
' -- "$@"
```

You can run a shell inside `sudo` and pass the script using `-c` option and specify the arguments to the shell. The quoting get's really hard, as you are inside quotes.

Alternatively and safer, you could create a temporary file, run it and remove it after your script execution. This let's you a bit more control.

```
cat >/tmp/tempfile.sh <<'EOF'
#!/bin/sh
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
  LOG_LOCATION="Base/reports/jtl_logs"
  CSV_LOCATION="Base/reports/csv"
  LOOP_COUNT=30
elif [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
  LOG_LOCATION="Base/reports/$1/jtl_logs"
  CSV_LOCATION="Base/reports/$1/csv"
  LOOP_COUNT=30
elif [ $# -eq 2 ]; then
  LOG_LOCATION="Base/reports/$1/jtl_logs"
  CSV_LOCATION="Base/reports/$1/csv"
  LOOP_COUNT=$2
fi

echo $LOG_LOCATION
echo $CSV_LOCATION
echo $LOOP_COUNT
EOF

sudo sh /tmp/tempfile.sh "$@"

rm /tmp/tempfile.sh
```

Or you could well pass the parameters to what you have now by specifying the input script for shell to be stdin:

```
sudo sh /dev/stdin "$@" <<'EOF'
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
LOG_LOCATION="Base/reports/jtl_logs"
CSV_LOCATION="Base/reports/csv"
LOOP_COUNT=30
elif [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
LOG_LOCATION="Base/reports/$1/jtl_logs"
CSV_LOCATION="Base/reports/$1/csv"
LOOP_COUNT=30
elif [ $# -eq 2 ]; then
LOG_LOCATION="Base/reports/$1/jtl_logs"
CSV_LOCATION="Base/reports/$1/csv"
LOOP_COUNT=$2
fi

echo $LOG_LOCATION
echo $CSV_LOCATION
echo $LOOP_COUNT
EOF
```

I don't like all three options specified above. Running such long scripts under `sudo` feels very unsafe. All the `if`s inside `sudo` look strange - why would you check the `$#` inside `sudo`? Why not do it in parent shell and only pass parsed variables to the command you only need to run via `sudo`? This feels like it violates a lot of least privilege principle - the `if`s nor the `echo`s, they doesn't need to be run as root at all.